# Simplify php code to select data from mysql database by column and sorting result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, select

I have built this code to select 250+ values from 2 tables in mysql.

I want to get the 10 numeric values corresponting to each name. 5 values from each table (table1 and table2)

From table1, I select the 5 corresponding values to the names and put them into an associative array. If the value is "-50", I unset the value.

From table2, the 5 corresponding values to the names correspond also to a value to the table1. I put them into an associative array and if the value is < 0.35, I unset the corresponding value of table1.

**I do all of this to sort each of 5 columns in table1 (Removing -50 and <0.35 values) from higher to lower.**

Selecting data from database:

```
//Names that correspond to 5 values in table1 and 5 in tab
$names = array(
'aatrox', 'ahri', 'akali', 'alistar', 'amumu', 'anivia', 'annie', 
'ashe', 'azir', 'bard', 'blitzcrank', 'brand', 'braum', 'caitlyn', 
'cassiopeia', 'chogath', 'corki', 'darius', 'diana', 'drmundo', 
'draven', 'ekko', 'elise', 'evelynn', 'ezreal', 'fiddlesticks', 'fiora', 
'fizz', 'galio', 'gangplank', 'garen', 'gnar', 'gragas', 'graves',  
'hecarim', 'heimerdinger', 'irelia', 'janna', 'jarvaniv', 'jax', 
'jayce', 'jinx', 'kalista', 'karma', 'karthus', 'kassadin', 'katarina', 
'kayle', 'kennen', 'khazix', 'kogmaw', 'leblanc', 'leesin', 'leona', 
'lissandra', 'lucian', 'lulu', 'lux', 'malphite', 'malzahar', 'maokai', 
'masteryi', 'missfortune', 'mordekaiser', 'morgana', 'nami', 'nasus',  
'nautilus', 'nidalee', 'nocturne', 'nunu', 'olaf', 'orianna', 
'pantheon', 'poppy', 'quinn', 'rammus', 'reksai', 'renekton', 'rengar', 
'riven', 'rumble', 'ryze', 'sejuani', 'shaco', 'shen', 'shyvana', 
'singed', 'sion', 'sivir', 'skarner', 'sona', 'soraka', 'swain',   
'syndra', 'tahmkench', 'talon', 'taric', 'teemo', 'thresh', 'tristana', 
'trundle', 'tryndamere', 'twistedfate', 'twitch', 'udyr', 'urgot', 
'varus', 'vayne', 'veigar', 'velkoz', 'vi', 'viktor', 'vladimir',   
'volibear', 'warwick', 'wukong', 'xerath', 'xinzhao', 'yasuo', 'yorick', 
'zac', 'zed', 'ziggs', 'zilean', 'zyra'
);

//Array for table1
$table1 = array();

//Array for table2
$table2 = array();

$numNames = count($names);

//Selecting 5 values (topratio, jungleratio, midratio, adcratio, supportratio) from table1 and corresponding them to their name.
for($i = 0; $i < $numNames; $i++){

    $query = $dbconn->query("SELECT topratio, jungleratio, midratio, 
                                    adcratio, supportratio 
                             FROM table1 
                             WHERE name = '".$names[$i]."' 
                             ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1"); 
    $table1[$names[$i]] = $query->fetch_assoc();
};

//Selecting 5 values (topdiapr, junglediapr, middiapr, adcdiapr, supportdiapr) from table2 and corresponding them to their name.
for($i = 0; $i < $numNames; $i++){

    $query = $dbconn->query("SELECT topdiapr, junglediapr, middiapr, 
                                   adcdiapr, supportdiapr 
                             FROM table2 
                             WHERE name = '".$names[$i]."' 
                             ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1"); 
    $table2[$names[$i]] = $query->fetch_assoc();
};
```

`print_r($table1)` returns something this:

```
Array ( 
    [Aatrox] => Array ( 
        [topratio] => 7.59 
        [jungleratio] => 0.55 
        [midratio] => -50 
        [adcratio] => -50 
        [supportratio] => -50 
    ) 
    [Ahri] => Array ( 
        [topratio] => -50 
        [jungleratio] => -50 
        [midratio] => 6.85 
        [adcratio] => -50 
        [supportratio] => -50 
    ) 
    ... 
    This continues until last name
)
```

Removing -50 values and <0.35

```
//I run 5 times this code because there are 5 columns in table1
for($b = 0; $b < 5; $b++){
    //If value corresponding to a name in table1 is -50, unset
    for($a = 0; $a < $numNames; $a++){
        if(($key = array_search(-50, $table1[$names[$a]])) !== false) {
            unset($table1[$names[$a]][$key]);
        }
    }
}

//If value corresponding to a name in table2 (topdiapr) is < than 0.35, unset corresponding value in table1 (topratio)
for($a = 0; $a < $numNames; $a++){
    if(($table2[$names[$a]][topdiapr])<0.35) {
        unset($table1[$names[$a]][topratio]);
    }
}

//Same that previous one but with junglediapr and jungleratio
for($a = 0; $a < $numNames; $a++){
    if(($table2[$names[$a]][junglediapr])<0.35) {
        unset($table1[$names[$a]][jungleratio]);
    }
}

//Same that previous one but with middiapr and midratio
for($a = 0; $a < $numNames; $a++){
    if(($table2[$names[$a]][middiapr])<0.35) {
        unset($table1[$names[$a]][midratio]);
    }
}

//Same that previous one but with adcdiapr and adcratio
for($a = 0; $a < $numNames; $a++){
    if(($table2[$names[$a]][adcdiapr])<0.35) {
        unset($table1[$names[$a]][adcratio]);
    }
}

//Same that previous one but with supportdiapr and supportratio
for($a = 0; $a < $numNames; $a++){
    if(($table2[$names[$a]][supportdiapr])<0.35) {
        unset($table1[$names[$a]][supportratio]);
    }
}
```

Finally, I get an array of each column and sort them from high to low:

```
//topratios list. This applies too to jungleratios, midratios, adcratios and supportratios.
$topratios = array();
for($c = 0; $c < $numNames; $c++){
    $topratios[$names[$c]] = $table1[$names[$c]][topratio];
}
$topratios = array_filter($topratios);
arsort($topratios);
```

Running this,

```
foreach ($supportratios as $key => $val) {
    echo 'Support: '.$key.'> '.$val.'<br>';
}
```

returns correctly what i wanted to get:

```
Support: Brand > 11.54
Support: Blitzcrank > 9.23
Support: Janna > 6.58
Support: Leona > 5.44
Support: Nami > 5.43
Support: Nautilus > 5.23
Support: Zyra > 4.66
Support: Soraka > 3.84
Support: Zilean > 3.71
Support: VelKoz > 2.22
Support: Braum > 2.22
Support: Bard > 2.14
Support: Sona > 1.46
Support: Thresh > 0.59
Support: Taric > 0.45
Support: Morgana > 0.37
Support: Shen > -0.77
Support: Alistar > -1.24
Support: Lulu > -1.7
Support: Kennen > -2.45
Support: Karma > -2.97
Support: Annie > -3.5
Support: Fiddlesticks > -5.38
Support: Tahm Kench > -7.98
```

**I wonder if there is a faster and simpler way** to make this. Also I would like to know if there is any alternative to executing 250+ queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know if this will help any but perhaps it might...

```
$names=array('aatrox', 'ahri', 'akali', 'alistar', 'amumu', 'anivia', 'annie', 'ashe', 'azir', 'bard', 
        'blitzcrank', 'brand', 'braum', 'caitlyn', 'cassiopeia', 'chogath', 'corki', 'darius', 'diana', 'drmundo', 
        'draven', 'ekko', 'elise', 'evelynn', 'ezreal', 'fiddlesticks', 'fiora', 'fizz', 'galio', 'gangplank', 
        'garen', 'gnar', 'gragas', 'graves', 'hecarim', 'heimerdinger', 'irelia', 'janna', 'jarvaniv', 'jax', 
        'jayce', 'jinx', 'kalista', 'karma', 'karthus', 'kassadin', 'katarina', 'kayle', 'kennen', 'khazix', 
        'kogmaw', 'leblanc', 'leesin', 'leona', 'lissandra', 'lucian', 'lulu', 'lux', 'malphite', 'malzahar', 
        'maokai', 'masteryi', 'missfortune', 'mordekaiser', 'morgana', 'nami', 'nasus', 'nautilus', 'nidalee', 
        'nocturne', 'nunu', 'olaf', 'orianna', 'pantheon', 'poppy', 'quinn', 'rammus', 'reksai', 'renekton', 
        'rengar', 'riven', 'rumble', 'ryze', 'sejuani', 'shaco', 'shen', 'shyvana', 'singed', 'sion', 'sivir', 
        'skarner', 'sona', 'soraka', 'swain', 'syndra', 'tahmkench', 'talon', 'taric', 'teemo', 'thresh', 
        'tristana', 'trundle', 'tryndamere', 'twistedfate', 'twitch', 'udyr', 'urgot', 'varus', 'vayne', 
        'veigar', 'velkoz', 'vi', 'viktor', 'vladimir', 'volibear', 'warwick', 'wukong', 'xerath', 'xinzhao', 
        'yasuo', 'yorick', 'zac', 'zed', 'ziggs', 'zilean', 'zyra');



$sql1="select `name`, `topratio`, `jungleratio`, `midratio`, `adcratio`, `supportratio` 
        from `table1` 
        where `name` in ('". implode( "','", $names ) ."')
        and ( `topratio` != -50 and `topratio` >= 0.35 )
        and ( `jungleratio` != -50 and `jungleratio` >= 0.35 )
        and ( `midratio` != -50 and `midratio` >= 0.35 )
        and ( `adcratio` != -50 and `adcratio` >= 0.35 )
        and ( `supportratio` != -50 and `supportratio` >= 0.35 );";



$sql2="select `name`, `topdiapr`, `junglediapr`, `middiapr`, `adcdiapr`, `supportdiapr` 
    from `table2` 
    where `name` in ('". implode( "','", $names ) ."')
    and ( `topratio` != -50 and `topratio` >= 0.35 )
    and ( `junglediapr` != -50 and `junglediapr` >= 0.35 )
    and ( `middiapr` != -50 and `middiapr` >= 0.35 )
    and ( `adcdiapr` != -50 and `adcdiapr` >= 0.35 )
    and ( `supportdiapr` != -50 and `supportdiapr` >= 0.35 )";
```

Comment: Ha.. you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add some normalization then using some simple joins, it will simplify your life considerably.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `champs` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT

CREATE TABLE `ratios_a` (
  `champ_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `top_r` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jungle_r` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mid_r` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adc_r` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `support_r` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`champ_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `ratios_b` (
  `champ_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `top_diapr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jungle_diapr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mid_diapr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adc_diapr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `support_diapr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`champ_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Select all based on conditions, using `PDO`.

**You can add `ORDER BY` in any query to achieve any sorting is needed.**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=lol;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = 'SELECT c.title, a.top_r, a.jungle_r, a.mid_r, a.adc_r, a.support_r, 
    b.top_diapr, b.jungle_diapr, b.mid_diapr, b.adc_diapr, b.support_diapr
FROM champs c
LEFT JOIN ratios_a a ON c.id=a.champ_id
LEFT JOIN ratios_b b ON c.id=b.champ_id
WHERE a.top_r != -50 AND a.jungle_r != -50 AND
a.mid_r != -50 AND a.adc_r !=-50 AND a.support_r != -50 AND
a.top_r >= 0.35 AND a.jungle_r >= 0.35 AND
a.mid_r >= 0.35 AND a.adc_r >= 0.35 AND a.support_r >= 0.35
AND
b.top_diapr != -50 AND b.jungle_diapr != -50 AND
b.mid_diapr != -50 AND b.adc_diapr !=-50 AND b.support_diapr != -50 AND
b.top_diapr >= 0.35 AND b.jungle_diapr >= 0.35 AND
b.mid_diapr >= 0.35 AND b.adc_diapr >= 0.35 AND b.support_diapr >= 0.35';

foreach($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result){
    print_r($result);
}
/* will output something like this
Array
(
    [title] => yasuo
    [top_r] => 5
    [jungle_r] => 10
    [mid_r] => 17
    [adc_r] => 13
    [support_r] => 1
    [top_diapr] => 19
    [jungle_diapr] => 0
    [mid_diapr] => 12
    [adc_diapr] => 10
    [support_diapr] => 20
)
Array
(
    [title] => yorick
    [top_r] => 3
    [jungle_r] => 13
    [mid_r] => 9
    [adc_r] => 9
    [support_r] => 2
    [top_diapr] => 13
    [jungle_diapr] => 15
    [mid_diapr] => 8
    [adc_diapr] => 8
    [support_diapr] => 20
)
*/
```

If you need only some specific ratios or you want stats for a specific champ, for example `support_ratio` and `support_diapr` just run a different query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.title, a.support_r, b.support_diapr
FROM champs c
LEFT JOIN ratios_a a ON c.id=a.champ_id
LEFT JOIN ratios_b b ON c.id=b.champ_id
WHERE c.id = 62 AND 
a.support_r != -50 AND a.support_r >= 0.35 AND
b.support_diapr != -50 AND b.support_diapr >= 0.35';


foreach($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result){
    print_r($result);
}

/* will output this
Array
(
    [title] => masteryi
    [support_r] => 5
    [support_diapr] => 8
)
*/
```